# Problem with editing LaTex in VS Code with TexLive after uninstalling MikTex

Tags: visual-studio-code, tex-live

I'm a noob at setting up LaTeX and I'm completely stuck. I had a broken MikTex + TexStudio setup that the previous owner of my work computer left behind (I also mention that I recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11). Unable to fix it, I decided to just wipe out everything and start clean. I uninstalled TexStudio and MikTex (also deleted all the files in AppData, etc.) and I installed TexLive (and gave the PC a restart as prescribed) to use it in VS Code (which I already had). All the guides I found say that once I install the LaTex Workshop extension in VS Code, everything should work on it's own (or at least no one mentions that there are problems that could arise).

However, when I try to compile a tex file I get the following error:

```
11 [0x00002528] INFO latexmk null - this process (19956) started by 'Code' with command line: latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/.../texfile_locationfolder" "c:/Users/.../texfile"


It seems that this is a fresh TeX installation.
Please finish the setup before proceeding.
For more information, visit:
https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-win
```

The fact that it mentions MikTex makes me think something messed up and VS Code is trying to use MikTex instead of TexLive. How can I fix this?

PS: I've tried to look at the settings for the VS Code extension, but there are dozens of settings options and, fairly enough, I don't have any idea what most of them do.

Comment: @KJ I did uninstall using the MikTex manager (it did give an error at the end about not being able to access some folder though)

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix: I went into the Environment Variables list and found that MikTex was still in there. After deleting everything related to MikTex in the PATH Environment Variables, all was working well. Yeey!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (on Windows). Resolved by deleting a MikTex folder, found by searching for MikTex in File Explorer.

Then, I deleted this folder from the recycling bin and restarted my computer. LaTeX Workshop detected TeXLive and works as expected.